# Passing data to child component via @Input is not triggering ngOnChanges and data is not being passed

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ivy, angular9

I'm trying to pass data from parent component to child component . The same code was working flawlessly before i upgraded to angular 9, I didn't even change anything in the code of this portion.

here is the parent component html template:

```
<tk-dynamic-form-builder [queryableFields]="['something' , 'somethingElse']" [fieldsData]="fieldsData"></tk-dynamic-form-builder>
<button type="button" (click)="reset()" class="reset-button" aria-label="Search" [disabled]="loading">
    <span *ngIf="!loading">Reset</span>
</button>
<button type="button" (click)="search()" class="submit-button" aria-label="Search" [disabled]="loading">
    <span *ngIf="!loading">Search</span>
    <span *ngIf="loading">Searching... <i class='fas fa-spinner fa-pulse'></i></span>
</button>
```

here is the child components relevant ts code:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'tk-dynamic-form-builder',
    templateUrl: './dynamic-form-builder.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dynamic-form-builder.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class DynamicFormBuilderComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

    @Input() queryableFields: any[];

    dateFormat: string;
    public myForm: FormGroup;
    public numberOfRows: number;
    public richTextFields: any[];




    formFields: any[] = [];        // is the array of fields objects
    formBuilderParameters: any;    // parameters given to formbuilder.group
    formFieldIds: string[] = [];   // is an array that represents only the formFieldIds
    numberOfColumns: number;
    @Input() fieldsData: any[];    // is the data in the form fields which gets presented on update
    @Input() isViewMode = false;

    constructor(private dateFormatService: DateFormatService,
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        private http: HttpClient,
        private main: MainService,
        private store: Store<DynamicProgramLibState>) {

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log("dynamic form builder initiated");
        this.store.pipe(select('loginState', 'formats')).subscribe(data => {
            this.dateFormat = data.dateFormat;
        });



    }

    ngOnChanges(): void {

        console.log("ngOnChanges Triggered");
        if (this.queryableFields) {
        //etc...
    }

    }

}
```

the app gets served and runs with no errors but the ngOnChanges in the child component is never triggered not even once, while this same code used to work before upgrading to angular 9.
one more thing to note is that this method of passing data is not working in the whole project and not just in this code sample.

any suggestions or recommendations would be highly appreciated

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle or codepen we can debug?

Comment: im sorry but the child component is too big and its state is dependent on ngrx store and external factors. i already simplified the code in a dummy project and it worked. so it's not working only in the scope of this project. so i was hoping someone would give me ideas where to look. (as in some config file that i need to configure)

Comment: If you simplified the complexity and was not able to reproduce the issue, that means is the problem is on the left behind part

Answer (score 1):

This is weird how it was working before but not now.

I also see you have `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, this changes it from the default.

Regardless if it is `Default` or `OnPush`, whenever you change `queryableFields` and `fieldsData`, change them immutably in your parent function. Basically, change the location of the address in memory for reference types (arrays or objects) for change detection to take place.

So in your parent component, whenever `queryableFields` changes do:

```
this.queryableFields = [...this.queryableFields, newValueHere];
// OR map for transformation
this.queryableFields = this.queryableFields.map(....); // map for a new reference
// OR filter for reduction
this.queryableFields = this.queryableFields.filter(....); // filter for a new reference
```

Same thing goes for `fieldsData`.

Comment: the fix was very simple actually...this code is in an angular library. and the way i was building the library was causing this malfunctionality. apparently in angular 9 projects, you have to add the --prod flag to the ng build when building to use the View engine. this wasn't the case in previous versions